# SQL: Select from Database up to a number (size)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I want to select rows up to a certain number (Size).
My SQL ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaed9/1)):

```
id  user_id     storage
1   1           1983349
2   1           42552
3   1           367225
4   1           1357899
37  1           9314493
```

I want to select only all rows up to a certain number (size).
Like this here:

```
Select * from uploads where storage < 410000
```

it should get something like this here:

```
id  user_id     storage
2   1           42552
3   1           367225
```

The Summary of ID '2' and '3' is 409777.

Comment: So you want the SUM() of the results?

Comment: No, I want to split the rows up to a certain number

Comment: Not clear what you want!

Answer (score 2):

You need some way of getting a cumulative sum.  In MySQL, the easiest way uses variables:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*, (@s := @s + storage) as cume_storage
      from uploads u cross join (select @s := 0) params
      order by id
     ) u
where cume_storage < 410000;
```

Comment: @gordon-linoff Could you explain it please?

Comment: @CrookieSusoku . . . It works fine.  Here is your SQL Fiddle with a more reasonable threshold:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaed9/33.